# Configuring rsnapshot to only daily backups with sync_first

Tags: rsnapshot

I want to create only daily backups in my server using `sync_first` option. How do I have to setup my server to backup once a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` set

```
snapshot_root   /backup/rsnapshot/
# ...
sync_first      1
```

and the retain rules to only daily:

```
#retain         hourly  6
retain          daily   7
```

In `/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot` also define to start rsync only daily and add the sync option:

```
#0 */4          * * *           root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
30 4    * * *           root    /opt/bin/rsnapshot sync && /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
```

Now when calling rsnapshot with verbose option:

```
rsnapshot -v sync
rsnapshot -v daily
```

you see an output like

```
/bin/cp -al /backup/rsnapshot/.sync /backup/rsnapshot/daily.0 
mv /backup/rsnapshot/daily.2/ /backup/rsnapshot/daily.3/  
mv /backup/rsnapshot/daily.1/ /backup/rsnapshot/daily.2/  
mv /backup/rsnapshot/daily.0/ /backup/rsnapshot/daily.1/  
/bin/cp -al /backup/rsnapshot/.sync /backup/rsnapshot/daily.0
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the '-v' option. Was having trouble understanding as to why 'at least one backup point must be set' for rotation only. It just needs to be present in the config file, but is never used..
Just for clarification: this scenario can occur, if you use several config files because of several origins having different ssh port configs. and then you want to be sure what happens when rotating to daily on one of the configs ..

Comment: Why are the first and last lines the same? `/bin/cp -al /backup/rsnapshot/.sync /backup/rsnapshot/daily.0`

Comment: because daily.0 is moved in the second last line